# How to represent elastic search dsl query in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

How to represent elastic search query shown below in spark with scala :

***Request***

```
GET importsmethods/typeimportsmethods/_search?search_type=count
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_imports": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tokens.importName"
      }
    }
  }
```

}

***Response***

```
{
   "took": 2064,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1297362,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "group_by_imports": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 4939,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 1960640,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "java.util.list",
               "doc_count": 129986
            },
            {
               "key": "java.util.map",
               "doc_count": 103525
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

***Spark Code***

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("test")

conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost")
conf.set("es.port", "9200")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create","true")
conf.set("es.resource","importsmethods/typeimportsmethods/_search")
conf.set("es.query","""?search_type=count&ignore_unavailable=true {
  "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
       "group_by_imports": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "tokens.importName"
         }
       }
     }
}""")

sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val importMethodsRDD = sc.esRDD();
val rddVal = importMethodsRDD.map(x => x._2) 

rddVal.saveAsTextFile("../")
```

***Exception***

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Index
>   [importsmethods/typeimportsmethods/_search] missing and settings
>   [es.field.read.empty.as.null] is set to false

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fix the following line, `es.resource` should only be [`index/type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#_reading_data_from_elasticsearch_5) no need to add the `_search` endpoint

```
conf.set("es.resource","importsmethods/typeimportsmethods")
```

Also, in `es.query` you don't need the query string, only the query DSL part:

```
conf.set("es.query","""{
  "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
       "group_by_imports": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "tokens.importName"
         }
       }
     }
}""")
```

Comment: I am getting this exception : ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[aggregations are not supported with search_type=scan]}]

Comment: Actually, aggregation support is [not yet possible](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/276) with pre 2.2 elasticsearch-hadoop releases. This feature is slated to be available in 2.2.0-rc1 (current estimate).